# Issues running a code using Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

OKay, so i wrote a code to develop a game using pygame. this is the aim of the game : 
there is a player (Mario) which can move only vertically. from the right side of the window, flames appear which the mario has to dodge. the game is very similar to dodger.py !
now, when i run the game, it gets stuck at "Press any key to Enter"

PLEASE HELP !

Comment: How about you include your code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try pressing the "any" key? :) Jokes aside, there is nothing set to do in the `waitForPlayerToPressKey()` function. The `if event.type == KEYDOWN:` only handles the `terminate` event, nothing else.

Comment: But the dodger game is running perfectly fine even without any addition for a case to check when other keys are pressed ? Whats the difference ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything in the `waitforkey()` function.

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    # if key exit blah blah
    else:
        runGame()
```

You could put your game in a function called runGame and that would probabaly be the easiest way of doing this. Just remember that the variables will then be local to the scope of *that* function and any changes won't affect the rest of the program.

Comment: then why is the dodger game running ? Even that code has no function like runGame. @Lawrence

Comment: @user3456011 I'm not aware of this dodger game, but I would guess that it would have the loop for the menu and then once the key is detected, the loop would break this would then move on to the next loop. However never having seen the code I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: The use of a blank return statement exits the current funtion. This means that when a key is pressed, the program will continue. You have this in your code to, so I can't see why you might get an error or freeze up. I can't run your code since I'm on iPhone right now, but it looks as though everything should run. I can't be sure but the next place I would imagine I problem forming is the use of two While True loops. Try taking one of them out.

Comment: could you please check this code when you are on a PC ?

Answer (score 0):

Having checked the code on a PC, I have found 3 errors. Two of which are typing errors. First one is on Line 77:

```
playerrect.topleft = (50,window_hight/2)
```

Needs to be:

```
playerrect.topleft = (50,window_height/2)
```

and the second is on line 126:

```
WindowSurface.fill(bgcolour)
```

You haven't defined `bgcolour` (as far as I could see) so by adding the following to the variables at the top of the file:

```
bgcolour(255,255,255) #change to what colour you want
```

The third error I found was in your `waitForKey()` function. I don't know whether this is important to the running of the program, but you have your `if event.type == "QUIT"` in speech marks. Like I said, this may not matter but I thought I'd point it out. You have also done this for the other conditions in this function.

By making these changes, you get running code. However, flames do not appear and I don't have time to figure this one out. By fiddling though, I'm sure you'll figure it out!